set width of parent element in css html
I have a example of this html :


.class-test {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:10px">
        <div class="class-test">
          aaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccccccccttttttt
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>



the result is always
aaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccccccccttttttt

even I have set my td width of 10px
I have read this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618121/css-set-width-to-parentnodes-width but still have the wrong result
For example, for 90px I want to see this result :

but in my real program the width of the td is change by changing the scroller zoom

I have remove it, I dont know how to copy here the correct code with this codepen

if you use max-width on your td it will behave maybe as you expected

You're asking the wrong question! add td { border: 2px dashed red } and you see what your actual issue is. The td resizes on its own. follow the comment of @DiegoD

The image you provide does not match the code you have provided. The codepen image  applies the width to the div... which is why it works.

You have a typo in the HTML you posted (also present in your screenshot). The last <td> before </tr> is supposed to be </td>. Fix that problem first.

@DiegoD I cant use max-width in my code...  I cant make  limmit to it

@PeterPointer i did

@hedbisker I'm not sure what you meant saying you can't limit the width of the td.. why then did you set it as <td style="width:10px"> ?? it seemed the intention was to make sure the size doesn't exceed that limit .. such behaviour will be assured with max-width instead. If you had further intentions I guess you need to rephrase the question

@DiegoD I mean that in my real code the width of the td is changing by scroll zoom of the mouse so this width is is not const and it changing dymanicly
for example this td can be look like that :  
and like that :    by the change of the zoom scroll

@hedbisker if you want your td width to strictly match its css width, set also its display: inline-block; .. that way as a block level element it will occupy a meaningful size set, in the document flow, despite its content

Add width and table-layout: fixed; and another <td> to the <table>. Then you will get what you expect:


table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: fit-content;
}

.class-test {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:90px">
      <div class="class-test">
        aaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccccccccttttttt
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>



